# Multiple Inheritance is possible in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop, c#-4.0

As per my previous knowledge, I always come to know that multiple inheritance is not possible in .NET. But if it is true, then I am confused when I have following code segment..

Suppose I have a class named `Employee`

```
class Employee{}
```

Then I am inheriting `Employee` class in another class named `Manager`

```
class Manager : Employee
{

}
```

Our every class, either defined in .NET class library or user-defined are always have `System.Object` as its base class. If it is true, then it means `Manager` class have two base classes, one is System.Object and another is `Employee`, where `System.Object` is being inherited implicitly and Employee class is being inherited explicitly, and `Manager` class has two base classes which forms Multiple Inheritance in place, which is actually impossible in .NET.

So, we can say that somewhere/somehow, multiple inheritance is possible, and if it is possible then why there is compile-time error when developers write code for it.

Comment: Multiple inheritance not directly possible in .NET.

Comment: You are confused -- this is not multiple inheritance.  Manager has one base class: Employee.  Employee has one base class System.Object.  Manager gets the goodies of System.Object by inheriting from Employee, it is not magically inheriting System.Object implicitly.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what multiple inheritance means. We talk about multiple inheritance when a class has 2 (or more) direct parent classes. A chain of classes inheriting from each other is still single inheritance regardless of how long the chain is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# only allows single inheritance. The System.Object class is inherited implicitly by your Employee class. So Manager class is-a Employee class, which is-a System.Object.

The compiler will handle this so you don't need to explicitly say that Class Employee  : System.Object.

In summary, every class inherits from System.Object. In case of Application level inheritance, only the top most class gets the System.Object as a base class.

Comment: KevDev, Somewhere your last line (In Summary, ... as a base class) justifies my question but can you please give me a link or document that verifies this statement.

Comment: The object browser will show it very clearly.

Comment: The point here is that System.Object is the [ultimate **base** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx). Classes can inherit from one other class, but the base application level class will always inherit from System.Object

Answer (score 0):

As KevDev and other users have stated, single inheritance is only possible in .NET. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that the [Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is *"This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework"*.

This is what single inheritance looks like:

[image: Single inheritance]

Notice the ** single direct** link between each class. Now here is what multiple inheritance looks like:

[image: Multiple inheritance]

Note that in the first picture, *all* classes are derived from the "super" or "base" class `Shape`. In the second picture, `Class C` inherits from both `Class A` **AND** `Class B` at the same time.

Try and think of the structure like this: For single inheritance, imagine you have a single line of people at a bus station. The gates (usually) only allow one person through at a time. Now if the gate is wide open, multiple people are able to walk through. Each person resembles one class.